# Microsoft Project not honoring closed tasks from TFS

Tags: tfs, ms-project

I am trying to pull some tasks to project from TFS. However when I pull over a parent node from a query in TFS it pulls all tasks under that node even though the query specifically excludes the closed items.

When I go to the get work item dialog it says there is only one item in a specific node and when I import it I get 80 items with 79 of them being closed.

Any ideas on how to not get the closed tasks I don't want?

Comment: What do you mean, "pull some tasks"?

Comment: In project there is a get work item button that brings up a dialog for the team projects in TFS you choose what query you want to look at and check the tasks you want to import and it pulls them from TFS into a project.

Comment: I have never seen such a button. When you say "in project", do you mean, "In Microsoft Project"?

Comment: Yes in Microsoft Project Professional 2013 under the team tab.